# Get value of autosplit delimiter?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

If I run a script with `perl -F`*something*, is that *something* value saved anywhere in the Perl environment where the script can find it?  I'd like to write a script that by default reuses the input delimiter (if it's a string and not a regular expression) as the output delimiter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/maint-5.22/toke.c#L4703), I don't think the delimiter is saved anywhere. When you run

```
perl -F, -an
```

the lexer actually generates the code

```
LINE: while (<>) {our @F=split(q\0,\0);
```

and parses it. At this point, any information about the delimiter is lost.

---

Your best option is to `split` by hand:

```
perl -ne'BEGIN { $F="," } @F=split(/$F/); print join($F, @F)' foo.csv
```

or to pass the delimiter as an argument to your script:

```
F=,; perl -F$F -sane'print join($F, @F)' -- -F=$F foo.csv
```

or to pass the delimiter as an environment variable:

```
export F=,; perl -F$F -ane'print join($ENV{F}, @F)' foo.csv
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, `perl -F, -an` is technically redundant; `-F` by itself implies both `-a` and `-n` (which you can override by manually specifying `-p`). Probably clearer to include them, although clarity is not usually a priority when you're writing a one-liner instead of a script to be saved. :)

Answer (score 1):

As @ThisSuitIsBlackNot says it looks like the delimiter is not saved anywhere.

This is how the [perl.c](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/0ba44c6301b83c358a9289cfe8c7bfc9cb38130d/perl.c#L3165) stores the `-F` parameter

```
case 'F':
PL_minus_a = TRUE;
PL_minus_F = TRUE;
    PL_minus_n = TRUE;
PL_splitstr = ++s;
while (*s && !isSPACE(*s)) ++s;
PL_splitstr = savepvn(PL_splitstr, s - PL_splitstr);
return s;
```

And then the lexer generates the code

```
LINE: while (<>) {our @F=split(q\0,\0);
```

However this is of course compiled, and if you run it with B::Deparse you can see what is stored.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -F/e/ -e ''
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    our(@F) = split(/e/, $_, 0);
}
-e syntax OK
```

Being perl there is always a way, however ugly. (And this is some of the ugliest code I have written in a while):

```
use B::Deparse;
use Capture::Tiny qw/capture_stdout/;
BEGIN {
    my $f_var;
}

unless ($f_var) {
    $stdout = capture_stdout {
        my $sub = B::Deparse::compile();
        &{$sub}; # Have to capture stdout, since I won't bother to setup compile to return the text, instead of printing
    };

    my (undef, $split_line, undef) = split(/\n/, $stdout, 3);
    ($f_var) = $split_line =~ /our\(\@F\) = split\((.*)\, \$\_\, 0\);/;
    print $f_var,"\n";  
}
```

Output:

```
$ perl -Fe/\\\(\\[\\\<\\{\"e  testy.pl
m#e/\(\[\<\{"e#
```

You could possible traverse the bytecode instead, since the start probably will be identical every time until you reach the pattern.

Comment: Well, that is impressive, but a little overkillish for my application.  I'll just do non-auto splitting.